# Timing my parser produces no output -- why?

Tags: bison, flex-lexer, yacc, lex

I am trying to measure the performance of my parser. Below is my main routine, which records the time before and after the parse. I am not getting any output. I put a debug printf statement after the first call to gettimeofday and it printed the initial time info correctly. I put a printf statement immediately after the call to fclose but it seems that control never got to the printf statement. Any ideas why I am not getting timing output? The parser works fine and prints things correctly (the parser parses an XML document, builds an Abstract Syntax Tree, and then serializes the AST).

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{  
     struct timeval start, end;
    
     // Start measuring time
     gettimeofday(&start, NULL);
    
     yyin = fopen(argv[1], "r");
     yyparse();
     fclose(yyin);
    
     // Stop measuring time and calculate the elapsed time
     gettimeofday(&end, NULL);
     printf("Time taken to parse is : %ld micro seconds\n",
           ((end.tv_sec * 1000000 + end.tv_usec) -
            (start.tv_sec * 1000000 + start.tv_usec)));
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Most likely, you're not actually returning from yyparse -- it crashes somewhere near the end (after it has produced what you do see) but before it gets back to main to print the time info.

Comment: This is why debuggers were invented.

Comment: Thank you @Chris Dodd. You were spot on. There was a problem in my treefree function and it wasn't terminating.